# Usage of the sign "+" meaning over

Tags: word-usage

How is the correct way in written English language: +100 or 100+?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question is a little unclear. What is the context? Either one might work depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to ask how to use numbers and a plus-sign to write something like, "over one-thousand," the answer is to place the plus-sign **after** the number:

> *How many people were at the game?*
>
> *Easily 1,000+.*

I cannot think of a situation in which one would place the '+' before the number.